# What options are there for using Zulu?

Tags: install4j

We need to migrate our OpenJDK-based application to Zulu, which uses install4j.

What approaches have the best long-term viability, in terms of EJ support and feasibility:

1. Offer pre-built bundles for download?
2. Install Zulu on a machine and run some scripts to massage the Zulu JDK into a JRE bundle?
3. Cross-platform capabilities for option 2., e.g. unpack a Mac Zulu on a Windows machine and run a script to generate a Mac bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As of install4j 8.0.7 there is no JDK provider for Zulu in install4j.
2. You can use "Project->Create a JRE bundle" or the command line tool `bin/createbundle" to create JRE bundles from Zulu installations.
3. There is no way to create JRE bundles in a cross-platform way for pre-created JRE bundles.